# Scanning a language with non-delimited strings with nested tokens

Tags: regex, parsing, flex-lexer, lex, lexer

I want to create a lexer/parser for a language that has non-delimited strings.
Which part of the language is a string is defined by the command preceding it.

For example it has statements that look like this:

```
pause 5
alert Hello world[CRLF] this contains 'pause' once (1)
```

Alert in this instance can end with any string, including keywords and numbers.
Further complicating things, the text can contain tags like [CRLF] that I want to separate too.
Ideally I'd want this to be broken up into:

```
[PAUSE][INT 5]
[ALERT][STR "Hello world"][CRLF][STR " this contains 'pause' once (1)"]
```

I'm currently using flex but from what I've gathered this kind of thing isn't possible with flex.
How can I achieve what I want here?

Comment: You might able to do this with start conditions, but it is far from clear what exactly you want to do. Does your input format actually have a grammar? Or is it just a keyword followed by unparsed text?

Comment: It has a grammar, it's basically always of the format "command arguments". The problem is that some commands have as their last argument a string which can potentially contain keywords and numbers. Essentially for some commands the last argument is an other language entirely that I want to parse in a different way. I don't want to separate keywords in those strings, but do want to separate tags. My main problem is that the lexer has to be kind of context-aware because what part is a string depends entirely on what command precedes it.I hope that explains it a bit better.

Comment: Start conditions look promising though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(Since one of your tags is "regex", I'll suggest a non-flex approach.)

From the example, it seems like you could just:

1. match each line against `^(\w+) (.+)` to obtain command and arguments-text, and then
2. get individual arguments by splitting the arguments-text on `(\[\w+\])` (assuming your regex library's split function can return both the splitter-strings and the split-strings).

It's possible your actual situation is more complex and something like flex makes more sense, but I'm not really seeing it so far.

Comment: Yes, the language is actually small enough that doing it manually like this is a viable option. I mainly wanted to use this language as an opportunity to learn flex (and how you would deal with weird languages like this). Thanks for the suggestion though.